# DHTMLXGantt Invalid Data

Tags: php, html, mysql, dhtmlx

I need to load MySQL data to DHTMLXGantt and I followed all the instructions here in the website (link: http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__how_to_start.html) yet it showed me an "Invalid Data" error. Where did I go wrong?

Here is my code:

```
    //myGantt.html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <title>How to Start with dhtmlxGantt</title>
       <script src="codebase/dhtmlxgantt.js"></script>
       <link href="codebase/dhtmlxgantt.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body{
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            height:100%;
            overflow:hidden;
        }   
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="gantt_here" style='width:1000px; height:400px;'></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var tasks = {
        data:[
            {id:1, text:"Project #1",start_date:"01-04-2013", duration:11,
            progress: 0.6, open: true},
            {id:2, text:"Task #1",   start_date:"03-04-2013", duration:5, 
            progress: 1,   open: true, parent:1},
            {id:3, text:"Task #2",   start_date:"02-04-2013", duration:7, 
            progress: 0.5, open: true, parent:1},
            {id:4, text:"Task #2.1", start_date:"03-04-2013", duration:2, 
            progress: 1,   open: true, parent:3},
            {id:5, text:"Task #2.2", start_date:"04-04-2013", duration:3, 
            progress: 0.8, open: true, parent:3},
            {id:6, text:"Task #2.3", start_date:"05-04-2013", duration:4, 
            progress: 0.2, open: true, parent:3}
        ],
        links:[
            {id:1, source:1, target:2, type:"1"},
            {id:2, source:1, target:3, type:"1"},
            {id:3, source:3, target:4, type:"1"},
            {id:4, source:4, target:5, type:"0"},
            {id:5, source:5, target:6, type:"0"}
        ]
    };
            gantt.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i";
            gantt.init("gantt_here");
            gantt.load('data.php');//loads data to Gantt from the database
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>`
```

Here's my data.php

```
    <?php

    include ('codebase/connector/gantt_connector.php');

    $res=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("dhtmlx");

    $gantt = new JSONGanttConnector($res);
    $gantt->render_links("gantt_links","id","source,target,type");
    $gantt->render_table(
    "gantt_tasks",
    "id",
    "start_date,duration,text,progress,sortorder,parent"
    );
    ?>
```

Here's my table:
gantt_links columns: id, source, target, type
gantt_tasks columns: id, text, start_date,duration,text,progress,sortorder,parent

Answer (score 1):

Such error fires when gantt.load receives an empty response - 
https://github.com/DHTMLX/gantt/blob/v3.1.1/codebase/sources/dhtmlxgantt.js#L4661

The connector code seems correct, but try opening data.php in browser to check what it returns. If it still shows nothing - make sure that php error reporting is enabled. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
Probably there'll be some issue like incorrect include path or database connection error.

Answer (score 0):

The example works, so you only have to check your side of things.

The php file must be exactly the one you see. If you use Dreamweaver, make sure you do not have other garbage in the file. It must contain only the example. begin with  The garbage will confuse the parser.

First you must input the data into the database.
There is a minimum of data to input. The list is on the page where you have got the example. I will not cut and paste here, go there and read it.

Open the data.php file in a browser and you will see if there is data from your query.

If you have no data retrieved, check your connections configuration and your privileges to read the database.

I have tested the example and it works.